# Incorrect submission of line breaks from Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Background: We are using Typescript and React to produce a browser-based replacement for a WinForms application. This front-end stores data through a C# API layer to a SQL database.

Problem: I have found that when using `<textarea>` to allow multi-line input and display, linebreaks are submitted by Chrome and Edge as LF only, whereas from Firefox these are CRLF. The [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element) states that LF should be used internally to determine length, etc, but should convert linebreaks to CRLF when submitting content.

> For historical reasons, the element's value is normalized in three
> different ways for three different purposes. The raw value is the
> value as it was originally set. It is not normalized. The API value is
> the value used in the value IDL attribute, textLength IDL attribute,
> and by the maxlength and minlength content attributes. It is
> normalized so that line breaks use U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters.
> Finally, there is the value, as used in form submission and other
> processing models in this specification. It is normalized so that line
> breaks use U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF) character
> pairs, and in addition, if necessary given the element's wrap
> attribute, additional line breaks are inserted to wrap the text at the
> given width.
>
> The algorithm for obtaining the element's API value is to return the
> element's raw value, with newlines normalized.
>
> The element's value is defined to be the element's raw value with the
> textarea wrapping transformation applied. The textarea wrapping
> transformation is the following algorithm, as applied to a string:
>
> Replace every occurrence of a U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) character not followed by a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character, and every
> occurrence of a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character not preceded by a
> U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) character, by a two-character string
> consisting of a U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF)
> character pair.
>
> If the element's wrap attribute is in the Hard state, insert U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF) character pairs into
> the string using an implementation-defined algorithm so that each line
> has no more than character width characters. For the purposes of this
> requirement, lines are delimited by the start of the string, the end
> of the string, and U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF)
> character pairs.

Is this an issue with Chrome/Edge and their implementation of HTML5, how React is handling the values, or our use of React?

The code creating the element results in:

```
const [text, setText] = setState<string>("");
<textarea
value={text}
onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Edit:
As a workaround I have modified the above code to

```
<textarea
value={text}
onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value
?.split(/\r?\n/).join('\r\n')
.split(/\r\n?/).join('\r\n'))}
/>
```

I am still interested to know if this is an issue with the browsers/React.

Comment: That is correct. I've added a link.

Answer (score 0):

### Change how the backend expects the data.

Some times I find C# does what C# wants, and it's easier to just write the correct implementation. During submit I would use JS to convert your text area into an array something like:

```
textArea.split("\n");
```

Then on C# expect a string[] and remerge it in C# something like

```
string.Join("correct CLFR character", textArea);
```

It's not a stellar solution, but some fights aren't worth fighting.

Comment: This wouldn't quite work as Firefox is returning \r\n from the textarea. See my edit for the work around we have implemented.